# .htaccess for PHP on OpenShift

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, openshift, url-routing

My directory structure is:

```
> app
   - controllers
   - core
   - includes
   - models
   - views
   - .htaccess
   - init.php
> public
   - css
   - fonts
   - images
   - js
   - .htaccess
   - index.php
```

The `.htaccess` file inside `public` directory is configured as:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And the one in `app` directory as:

```
Options -Indexes
```

I have hosted the application on OpenShift. Though this configuration works well locally but throws `500 Server Error` on OpenShift. Help?

Comment: Check server's error logs

Comment: What is url that you write in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that the 'public' directory is being selected as your document root, and the files in app are not web accessible because they are outside of the document root.  You can see how the document root is chosen here (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-php/usr/lib/php_config), you should also check your log files (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html) to get more information about the error that is being generated.